# How to setup the Hyperlink from one page to another page in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am new to Oracle APEX. My requirement is to setup a Hyperlink from one page to another page.

Currently I am displaying 4 columns in the report of Page 1. The report is like below,

Survey Response Count_of_Cities City_Name

AB       Y        2               LONDON,CHICAGO
AB       N        3               DELHI,MUMBAI,CHENNAI
AC       Y        1               LONDON
AC       N        4               TOKYO,HONGKONG,BANGALORE,HYDERABAD

But the revised requirement is I need to show the City_name in another page i.e. Page 2 when the user clicks on value of the Count_of_Cities. i.e. If the user clicks on 3, In page 2 the values should be appear like below
DELHI
MUMBAI
CHENNAI

If I click on the 4, the values in the page should be like below,

TOKYO
HONGKONG
BANGALORE
HYDERABAD

Currently in Page 1 I am hiding the City_Name and created a Hyperlink on Count_of_Cities. When clicked on Count_of_Cities it is navigating to Page 2. But the values for City_Name are not showing properly.

Please sugegst how I can show the City_Name values in page 2?

Please let me know if you require any additional information.

Edited by: 980540 on Jan 9, 2013 2:02 AM

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have a report on page one, and you wish to use a column link on Count_Of_Cities to move to page two and save the state of City_Name to be used on page 2.

How are you currently attempting to transfer the value to page 2?

1)Create a hidden item on page 2 named P2_CITY_NAME or similar.

2)On page 1, open the "Report Columns" branch under the report and double click on the column Count_Of_Cities (or double click on the report, click the report attributes tab, and then the pencil/edit icon next to the Count_Of_Cities.

3)Scroll to the Column Link area, and set

```
Target=Page in this Application
Page=2
Item1=P2_CITY_NAME
Value=#Count_Of_Cities#
```

If this doesn't work, tell me what URL is being pointed to when you hover your mouse over the column link in Count_Of_Cities.

Comment: [Doubt you'll get an answer. Crossposting between OTN and SO is very common here.](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2484106&tstart=30) Not even taking the time to format the question, or provide answers/feedback :(

Comment: I've been crossposting between OTN and SO as well (for APEX questions only) but I make sure to provide the answer I receive on SO back to OTN. Is this ok?

Comment: of course this is ok! I only get annoyed when you see posts like the above never to receive any follow up again. There are enough unanswered questions here in this manner, and flagging them with appropriate reasons only sometimes gets them deleted. That grieves me just a bit :-)